# Editing EPS and AI (Adobe Illustrator) files with PHP

Tags: php, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm looking for PHP tool to edit *.eps or *.ai files? I need to add any new shapes or text to these files. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't overestimate the complexity of a picture. For PSD files I found the following: 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3627-PHP-Open-images-in-the-PhotoShop-PSD-format.html#download **(link is broken; package doesn't exist)**
In the end the script isn't even very complex. It's just a matter of knowing which bytes to pick. 
I could imagine that for `.ai` files, there's something similar...

Answer (score 1):

Recently, `.ai` files have similar format to PDF (files produced about 2000 and newer). I've successfully opened `.ai` files with a PDF viewer such as MUPDF after renaming them with a .pdf extension. If this works for you, any PHP tool for PDF files should work for AI files.